# Can we pass variable in jQuery instead of class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am a student and learner, I am making a star rating function using jQuery. Here is my code:
HTML Code:

```js
for (var i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
  console.log(i);
  var cls = ".star_".concat(i);
  var sp_cls = ".star_color_".concat(i);
  console.log(cls);
  $(cls).click(function() {
    $(sp_cls).toggleClass(sp_cls);
    $("#rate").html("<b>Hello world!</b>");
    console.log(i);
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Rating Stars Box -->
<div class='rating-stars text-center p-2 mt-3'>
  <h5 id="rate">Rate this answer here!</h5>
  <ul id='stars'>
    <li class='star_1' title='Poor' data-value='1'>
      <span class='star_color_1'>
                <i class='fa fa-star fa-fw fa-2x'></i>
            </span>
    </li>
    <li class='star_2' title='Fair' data-value='2'>
      <span class='star_color_2'>
                <i class='fa fa-star fa-fw fa-2x'></i>
            </span>
    </li>
    <li class='star_3' title='Good' data-value='3'>
      <span class='star_color_3'>
                <i class='fa fa-star fa-fw fa-2x'></i>
            </span>
    </li>
    <li class='star_4' title='Excellent' data-value='4'>
      <span class='star_color_4'>
                <i class='fa fa-star fa-fw fa-2x'></i>
            </span>
    </li>
    <li class='star_5' title='WOW!!!' data-value='5'>
      <span class='star_color_5'>
                <i class='fa fa-star fa-fw fa-2x'></i>
            </span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

In this I am passing variable named "cls" instead of class name, it is not showing any error in console but my program is not working. Why so?

Comment: We need your HTML as well to help you. Can you add that too, please? Also, what does this do? `"star_color_".concat(i);` instead, you could have used `"star_color_" + i`. Create a [mcve]. Also, use a DOM Selector with either `.` or `#` prepended.

Comment: Also you should be using `let i = 1` instead of `var i = 1`. Refer this issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42757887/javascript-closure-event-handler-issue#

Answer (score 1):

You code looks very similar to this snippet here:

> https://codepen.io/mmoradi08/pen/yLyYrGg

I took the liberty of converting that code into a jQuery plugin and cleaned it up a bit. I am not sure you would need to modify it any further.

You can call the plugin, as seen below, by invoking the function on the jQuery object. It takes an optional config with a callback function.

```js
$('.rating-stars').ratingWidget({
  callback: responseMessage
});
```

```js
/* jquery.rating-widget.js */
($ => {
  const defaultConfig = { callback: null  };
  $.fn.ratingWidget = function(config) {
    const opts = { ...defaultConfig, ...config };
    this.find('ul li').on({
      mouseover: function() {
        const currRating = parseInt($(this).data('value'), 10);
        $(this).parent().children('li.star').each(function(index) {
          $(this).toggleClass('hover', index < currRating);
        });
      },
      mouseout: function() {
        $(this).parent().children('li.star').removeClass('hover');
      },
      click: function() {
        const currRating = parseInt($(this).data('value'), 10);
        $(this).parent().children('li.star').each(function(index) {
          $(this).toggleClass('selected', index < currRating)
        });
        const last = $(this).parent().find('li.selected').last();
        if (opts.callback) opts.callback(parseInt(last.data('value'), 10));
      }
    });
  };
})(jQuery);

$('.rating-stars').ratingWidget({
  callback: responseMessage
});

function responseMessage(rating) {
  var msg = rating > 1
    ? `Thanks! You rated this ${rating} stars.`
    : `We will improve ourselves. You rated this ${rating} stars.`;
  console.log(msg);
}
```

```css
/* Rating stars */
.rating-stars {
}

.rating-stars ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 100%;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
}

.rating-stars ul>li.star {
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* Idle State of the stars */
.rating-stars ul>li.star>i.fa {
  font-size: 2.5em;
  color: #ccc;
}

/* Selected and hovered state of the stars */
.rating-stars ul>li.star.selected.hover>i.fa {
  color: #2C91FF;
}

/* Selected state of the stars */
.rating-stars ul>li.star.selected>i.fa {
  color: #FF912C;
}

/* Hover state of the stars */
.rating-stars ul>li.star.hover>i.fa {
  color: #FFCC36;
}

.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 4em !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.14.0/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="rating-stars">
  <ul id="stars">
    <li class="star" title="Poor" data-value="1">
      <i class="fa fa-star fa-fw"></i>
    </li>
    <li class="star" title="Fair" data-value="2">
      <i class="fa fa-star fa-fw"></i>
    </li>
    <li class="star" title="Good" data-value="3">
      <i class="fa fa-star fa-fw"></i>
    </li>
    <li class="star" title="Great" data-value="4">
      <i class="fa fa-star fa-fw"></i>
    </li>
    <li class="star" title="Amazing" data-value="5">
      <i class="fa fa-star fa-fw"></i>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`$(##)` expects DOM selector, not only class `.star_1`:

```html
<div class="star_1"></div>
```

you pass selector `star_1`, so jQuery searches for that element

```html
<start_1></star_1>
```

and it's most likely you use classes/id's but not custom elements, that's why it's not working.

Comment: what if we concat using ".star_" so that it could identify it as a class

Answer (score 0):

You are having `$(sp_cls).toggleClass(sp_cls);` where `sp_cls='.star_color_1'`, so in case of `selector` `$(sp_cls)` it is correct but in parameter value for `toggleClass` you should pass value `without dot (.)`. You can use `sp_cls.slice(1)` which will return string from `1st` index.

Moreover `$(sp_cls).toggleClass(sp_cls);` will remove `class` from the `element` next time when it will come to this line `$(sp_cls)` will not find any matching element. You should consider using different class in `toggleClass` like `active` etc. - Just a suggestion though.

Second thing you should **learn about `closure`.** Here your code will start working with above code but when you click on element it will always have `sp_cls` as `star_color_5` and `i = 6`.

To capture value **you must declare `i` using `let` instead of `var` in `for (let i = 1; i < 6; i++)`**. Here are references

- [Creating closures in loops A common mistake](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures#Creating_closures_in_loops_A_common_mistake),
- [Javascript Closure Event Handler Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42757930/9695286),
- [How do JavaScript closures work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work).

Your updated function would be like below.

```
for (let i = 1; i < 6; i++) {  
    var cls = ".star_".concat(i);
    var sp_cls = ".star_color_".concat(i);
    $(cls).click(function() {
        $(sp_cls).toggleClass(sp_cls.slice(1));
        $("#rate").html("<b>Hello world!</b>");
        console.log(i);
    });
}
```

Try it below.

```js
for (let i = 1; i < 6; i++) {  
  var cls = ".star_".concat(i);
  var sp_cls = ".star_color_".concat(i);
  $(cls).click(function() {
    $(sp_cls).toggleClass(sp_cls.slice(1));
    $("#rate").html("<b>Hello world!</b>");
    console.log(i);
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Rating Stars Box -->
<div class='rating-stars text-center p-2 mt-3'>
  <h5 id="rate">Rate this answer here!</h5>
  <ul id='stars'>
    <li class='star_1' title='Poor' data-value='1'>
      <span class='star_color_1'>
        <i class='fa fa-star fa-fw fa-2x'></i>
      </span>
    </li>
    <li class='star_2' title='Fair' data-value='2'>
      <span class='star_color_2'>
        <i class='fa fa-star fa-fw fa-2x'></i>
      </span>
    </li>
    <li class='star_3' title='Good' data-value='3'>
      <span class='star_color_3'>
          <i class='fa fa-star fa-fw fa-2x'></i>
      </span>
    </li>
    <li class='star_4' title='Excellent' data-value='4'>
      <span class='star_color_4'>
        <i class='fa fa-star fa-fw fa-2x'></i>
      </span>
    </li>
    <li class='star_5' title='WOW!!!' data-value='5'>
      <span class='star_color_5'>
        <i class='fa fa-star fa-fw fa-2x'></i>
      </span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```